# Custom search paths

Tags: search, uri

I want "random/search/node/keywords" be the same as "search/node/keywords", or to be more precise, I need the "random/" at some part of the URL, so I can enable certain blocs on a certain search page. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Drupal 7

Comment: You probably do a hook_menu_alter() implementation that just copies the existing search menu items over to your new path... but I feel like you're probably trying to approach this incorrectly... say more about the blocks you want to add and when you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You could rebuild the search page using views under any custom path. Have a look at http://drupal.org/project/search_api for more possibilities.

Regarding the block visibility: you can use `*/search/node/keyword`.